# Ejecutar método de un controlador dentro de otro controlador - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una base de datos con dos tablas relacionadas de esta forma **factura hasOne Imagen**.

La idea es que cada vez que creo una factura se le asocie una imagen que ya esta creada en la base de datos con anterioridad. Al ejecutar el método store del FacturaController debería modificarse la tabla imagen el campo **factura_id**, con el ID de la factura recién creada.

Este es mi método Store de FacturaController:

```
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(SaveFacturaRequest $request)
{


        $cliente_id = request('cliente_id');
        $rnc_cedula = request('rnc_cedula');
        $bienes = request('bienes');
        $ncf = request('ncf');
        $ncf_modificado = request('ncf_modificado');
        $date_comp = request('date_comp');
        $date_pago = request('date_pago');
        $tipo_bien = request('tipo_bien');
        $monto_servicios = request('monto_servicios');
        $monto_bienes = request('monto_bienes');
        $itebis_fact = request('itebis_fact');
        $itebis_retenido = request('itebis_retenido');
        $itebis_sujeto = request('itebis_sujeto');
        $itebis_costo = request('itebis_costo');
        $tipo_retencion = request('tipo_retencion');
        $monto_ret = request('monto_ret');
        $isr = request('isr');
        $impuesto_selec = request('impuesto_selec');
        $otras_tasas = request('otras_tasas');
        $propina = request('propina');
        $forma_pago = request('forma_pago');
        $operador = auth()->user()->name;




    Factura::create([
        'cliente_id'=> $cliente_id,
        'rnc_cedula'=> $rnc_cedula,
        'bienes'=> $bienes,
        'ncf'=> $ncf,
        'ncf_modificado'=> $ncf_modificado,
        'date_comp'=> $date_comp,
        'date_pago'=> $date_pago,
        'tipo_bien'=> $tipo_bien,
        'monto_servicios'=> $monto_servicios,
        'monto_bienes'=> $monto_bienes,
        'itebis_fact'=> $itebis_fact,
        'itebis_retenido'=> $itebis_retenido,
        'itebis_sujeto'=> $itebis_sujeto,
        'itebis_costo'=> $itebis_costo,
        'tipo_retencion'=> $tipo_retencion,
        'monto_ret'=> $monto_ret,
        'isr'=> $isr,
        'impuesto_selec'=> $impuesto_selec,
        'otras_tasas'=> $otras_tasas,
        'propina'=> $propina,
        'forma_pago'=> $forma_pago,
        'operador'=> $operador,
    ]);


    return redirect()->route('home.index');

}
```

Esta es la vista del formulario para crear la facturas:

```
                @csrf
            <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            <form class="form-inline ml-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">

                        <label>Cliente: {{ $ruta->cliente->nombre_cliente }}</label>
                        <input type="hidden"  name="cliente_id"  value="{{ $ruta->cliente->id }}">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>RNC / Cédula</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" id="rnc_cedula" name="rnc_cedula" value="{{old('rnc_cedula', $factura->rnc_cedula ?? '')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Tipo de bienes y servicios</label>
                            <select class="custom-select" name='bienes' id="bienes" value="{{old('bienes', $factura->bienes ?? '')}}" >
                                <option>01 Gasto de personal</option>
                                <option>02 Compras por trabajos suministros y servicios</option>
                                <option>03 Arrendamiento</option>
                                <option>04 Gastos de activo fijo</option>
                                <option>05 Gastos de representacion</option>
                                <option>06 Otras deduciones admitidas</option>
                                <option>07 Gastos financieros</option>
                                <option>08 Gastos extraordinarios</option>
                                <option>09 Compras y gastos que forman parte del costo de venta</option>
                                <option>10 Adquisiciones de activo</option>
                                <option>11 Gastos de seguro </option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>NCF</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="ncf" id="ncf" value="{{old('ncf', $factura->ncf ?? '')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>NCF/Documento modificado</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="ncf_modificado" id="ncf_modificado" value="{{old('ncf_modificado', $factura->ncf_modificado ?? '')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Fecha de comprobante</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_comp" id="date_comp" value="{{old('date_comp', $factura->date_comp ?? $imagen->date)}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Fecha de pago</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_pago" id="date_pago" value="{{old('date_pago', $factura->date_pago ?? '')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Tipo de bien facturado</label>
                            <select class="custom-select" name='tipo_bien' id="tipo_bien" value="{{old('tipo_bien', $factura->tipo_bien ?? '')}}" >
                                <option>Monto Facturado en Servicios</option>
                                <option>Monto Facturado en Bienes</option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Monto facturado en servicios</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="monto_servicios" id="monto_servicios" value="{{old('monto_servicios', $factura->monto_servicios ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Monto facturado en bienes</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="monto_bienes" id="monto_bienes" value="{{old('monto_bienes', $factura->monto_bienes ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>ITBIS facturado</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="itebis_fact" id="itebis_fact" value="{{old('itebis_fact', $factura->itebis_fact ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>ITBIS retenido</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="itebis_retenido" id="itebis_retenido" value="{{old('itebis_retenido', $factura->itebis_retenido ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>ITBIS sujeto a proporcionalidad</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="itebis_sujeto" id="itebis_sujeto" value="{{old('itebis_sujeto', $factura->itebis_sujeto ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>ITBIS llevado al costo</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="itebis_costo" id="itebis_costo" value="{{old('itebis_costo', $factura->itebis_costo ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Tipo de retención</label>
                            <select class="custom-select" name='tipo_retencion' id="tipo_retencion" value="{{old('tipo_retencion', $factura->tipo_retencion ?? '0')}}" >
                                <option>01 Alquileres</option>
                                <option>02 Honorarios por servicios</option>
                                <option>03 Otras rentas</option>
                                <option>04 Otras rentas ( rentas presuntas)</option>
                                <option>05 intereses pagados a personas juridicas residentes</option>
                                <option>06 Intereses pagados a personas fisicas residentes</option>
                                <option>07 Retenciones por proveedores del estado</option>
                                <option>08 Juegos telefonicos</option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Monto de retención de renta</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="monto_ret" id="monto_ret" value="{{old('monto_ret', $factura->monto_ret ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>ISR persivido en compras</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="isr" id="isr" value="{{old('isr', $factura->isr ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Impuesto selectivo al consumo</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="impuesto_selec" id="impuesto_selec" value="{{old('impuesto_selec', $factura->impuesto_selec ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Otras tasas e impuestos</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="otras_tasas" id="otras_tasas" value="{{old('otras_tasas', $factura->otras_tasas ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Monto propina legal</label>
                            <input type="string" class="form-control" name="propina" id="propina" value="{{old('propina', $factura->propina ?? '0')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Forma de pago</label>
                            <select class="custom-select" name='forma_pago' id="forma_pago" value="{{old('forma_pago', $factura->forma_pago ?? '')}}" >
                                <option>01 Efectivo</option>
                                <option>02 Cheque / Transferencia</option>
                                <option>03 Tarjeta de crédito / débito</option>
                                <option>04 Compras a crédito</option>
                                <option>05 Permuta</option>
                                <option>06 Nota de crédito</option>
                                <option>07 Mixto</option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">{{ $btnText }}</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Todavía no he definido como sera el método Update de ImagenController.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Me gustaria saber como modificar un campo de la tabla imagen al momento de crear un nuevo registro de factura.